# Shuffle a 2d list in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python. I have a Python 2D array `[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,j]]` and would like to shuffle the 3 inner lists but not the contents. I can't seem to access numpy but would think this is quite simple. shuffle does not seem to work for a 2d array as it returns none. HELP Please!!

I would like something like `[[d,e,f],[a,b,c],[g,h,j]]` for example...

Comment: Thanks the first example works great. Confusing as I thought that was the code I was using last night and getting None returned. I tried to use Nunpy as well but I could not figure out away to import it into IDLE as it seemed not to be installed. Anyway my list is now shuffled, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `shuffle` from `random`:

```
import random
arr = [list('abc'), list('def'), list('ghj')]
>>> arr
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'j']]

random.shuffle(arr)
```

Example output:

```
>>> arr
[['g', 'h', 'j'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Or, you could do the same with `numpy.random.shuffle`:

```
import numpy as np
arr = [list('abc'), list('def'), list('ghj')]
>>> arr
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'j']]
np.random.shuffle(arr)
>>> arr
[['g', 'h', 'j'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```